# Creating an ASP.Net Web Application with details below:

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2017

How to save history of user last login and display right after user login  in login screen.

I have shared the code in which I have implemented for the user session login. I am checking for any help with explanation will be appreciated.

**User Login and Validation Code:**

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel login)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (new UserEntity().isValidUser(login.EmailId, login.Password))
        {
            Session["login"] = login;
            //Redirect to Employee Controller after Validation
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Employee");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.InvalidUser = "Invalid User Name or
       Password";
        return View(login);
        }
    }
    return View(login);
}

public Boolean isValidUser(string emailId, string password)
{
    Boolean isValid = false;
    try
    {
        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        string query = @"Select * from UserProfile
where EmailID='" + emailId + "' and
   Password = '"+password+"'";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dataReader.Read())
        {
            isValid = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        //exception logging
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: Hey Mark, I think it would be easier for anyone to help, if you show something you have tried. It's really difficult to help someone code something from scratch with no relevant context or anything. Cheers.

Comment: @thesystem I have updated the question as you mentioned.

Comment: Since you return the LoginViewModel (`login`), could it be an idea to include some properties or fields in there that would display the last login time? And then you need to retrieve from the database last time user logged in. I am not the most experienced with Razor markup, but good that you added more code - makes it easier to get an idea.

Comment: @thesystem this is actually what I want to know about like what to do that would display the last login time and I am currently struck because of this issue.

Comment: Do you have the last login time stored in the database, or how do you store the information, that you need to display?

Comment: Because I think you would need to actually save the login time to a database, everytime a user logs in. Then, next time a user logs in, then you need to fetch this data from the database.

I don't know if there is some built-in feature in your database provider, that holds this information.

I am sorry that I wasn't of more help, but wish you best of luck - and I hope somebody else comes through to help.

Comment: @thesystem I am thinking the same to save the login time to a database, every time  when a user logs in but I cannot find the built-in feature to hold this information but thanks a lot you guide me quite well in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an attempt to try and (hopefully) guide you further in the right direction. I am not sure that there is a built-in feature that holds this information, so we may need to store the data manually. Maybe it could be something like this:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel login)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        SaveLoginTimeToDatabase(); //here, we call a method that we define ourselves
        ... //rest of your original code
    }
    return View(login);
}

public void SaveLoginTimeToDatabase()
{
    DateTime loginTime = new DateTime().Now;
    sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    string query = @"Insert* into UserLoginTimeTable
   VALUES (User.Email, loginTime)";
   //So, we need to create a new database table, UserLoginTimeTable, for this info
   //... Rest of code: open SQL connection, execute etc.
}
```

However, we also need to display the login time when user logs in, so we need a method for that. To do that, we probably a field on your Razor login-page, where that information can be displayed.
Then, in the login method, we call a new method to fetch that data

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel login)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var lastLogin = FetchLastLoginTime(login.EmailId); //new method for retrieving the data
        // you need to call it before SaveLoginTime...(), so that you dont get the current login, that will be saved in the next line
        SaveLoginTimeToDatabase();
       //you may need to include lastLogin in your loginViewModel:
         login.LastLogin = lastLogin;
        ... //rest of your original code
    }
    return View(login); 
}


public DateTime FetchLastLoginTime(string emailId)
{
    sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    string query = @"Select TOP 1 from UserLoginTimeTable
    Where EmailID = ' emailId"
    //Open sql connection, execute etc
    //Now, you should have access to the last time that user logged in. Return it to the original method and display it
var lastLogin = //get the logintime from the query
return lastLogin;
}
```

This is not a definitive answer and may have incorrect syntax, but just an overall attempt to show how you maybe can go about it. You don't need to accept it as answer, it's just a suggestion that you hopefully can make work. Since you would need multiple queries to the database like this, you may need to implement some asynchronous behaviour with await/async, unit of work/transactions or similar, but hopefully it just works.

So to sum up, with this approach you need a new database table, queries and additional logic. You are always welcome to tag me/write if you have more questions, you think I can help with (hopefully you can use some of this), best of luck